# Unable to find elements in Angular JS application using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am new to work with Angular JS application testing . I have tried with sample Angular JS apps which are available in online.

Link : [Angular JS application](http://themeforest.net/item/square-responsive-admin-app-with-angularjs/full_screen_preview/7511722)

After explore in the net Protractor is the best way to test AngularJS. I have tried with followed code for finding elements in above link. Itried with all possible locators , but unable catch any web element .

Protractor version: 2.5.1

Code:

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {

  it( 'should load the home page', function() {
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
      browser.get('http://themeforest.net/item/square-responsive-admin-app-with-angularjs/full_screen_preview/7511722');
      browser.driver.manage().window().maximize()
      browser.sleep(6000);
      element(by.xpath('.//*[@id="nav"]/li[2]/a')).click();
  });
});
```

Config file::

```
exports.config = {
    //The address of a running selenium server.
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
 //Here we specify the name of the specs files.
  specs: ['testspec.js']
}
```

Error:

```
 1) angularjs homepage should load the home page
   Message:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"na
v\"]/li[2]/a")
   Stacktrace:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"na
v\"]/li[2]/a")
    at new bot.Error (C:\Users\CP042756\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protrac
tor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108:18)
    at C:\Users\CP042756\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element
.js:694:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\CP042756\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:130:
15)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:9)
Error
```

Please help and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi your element is located inside the iframe before u try to click on this link you have to switch to iframe using browser.switchTo().frame("NAME OF YOUR IFRAME");

For more information on [Selenium Iframe](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-work-with-iframes-in-selenium-webdriver)

```
browser.switchTo().frame("preview-frame"); 
element(by.xpath('.//*[@id="nav"]/li[2]/a')).click();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The desired element is inside an `iframe` - [switch to it's context](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.TargetLocator.prototype.frame) before looking for an element:

```
browser.switchTo().frame("preview-frame"); 
element(by.xpath('.//*[@id="nav"]/li[2]/a')).click();
```

`preview-frame` is the name of the `iframe`.

---

As you may already know, your AngularJS application is loaded in this `iframe` - this is probably why you set that `ignoreSynchronization` flag.

I think you can test your application without turning the sync off and having the need to tweak `ignoreSynchronization` flag at all - the `data-ng-app` attribute is set on the `body` inside the `iframe`. If you go directly to the URL from where the `iframe` is loaded, `protractor` would automatically detect your AngularJS application and would work with it in sync:

```
it('should load the home page', function() {
  browser.get('http://iarouse.com/dist-square/v2.0.1/index.html');
  browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

  element(by.xpath('.//*[@id="nav"]/li[2]/a')).click();
});
```